# Sum up values and delete rows from a table in Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Consider the following table

```
create table Test1
(
id number(5),
batch number(5),
value number(10)
);

Insert into test1 values(1,10,200);
Insert into test1 values(2,10,700);
Insert into test1 values(3,10,400);
Insert into test1 values(1,20,1000);
Insert into test1 values(2,20,100);
Insert into test1 values(3,20,5000);
commit;
```

Now, the requirement here is to retain only 1 row per Batch and add all values for the batch and assign it to the Id (Min Id chosen here) being retained. Remaining rows for the Batch should be deleted. This should happen as soon as the rows are inserted for a Batch.

Expected result

```
Id Batch Value
1  10    1300
1  20    1600
```

The existing system has a logic wherein there is an After Insert or Update Trigger on Test1 which calls a Package through dbms_job. Inside this Package, the Update and Delete happens.

```
Create or replace trigger Trigger_Test_1
After Insert or Update of Value on Test_1
For Each row
Begin
...
dbms_job(call to package Pkg_Test_1.Proc_1(:New.Id, :New.Batch));
...
End;

Create or Replace Package Body Pkg_Test_1
As
Procedure Proc_Test_1(p_id number, p_batch number) Is
Begin
Select Min(Id), Batch, sum(Value)
Into v_id, v_batch, value_sum
From Test1
Where Batch = p_batch
Group by Batch
Having count(*) > 1;

If (v_id is not null) then
 update test1
 set value = value_sum
 where id = v_id;

 delete from test1
 where id <> v_id
 and batch = p_batch;
commit;
End If;

End;
End;
```

The issue lies during Update where another call to Trigger(Trigger_Test_1) takes place which results in value getting updated in an infinite loop. Finally I had to delete the record to stop the update.
This is an awkward situation and I know that writing such logic inside trigger is not recommendable but this is the existing logic in our system.

Any ideas about how I can improve the code or how this result can be achieved in a different manner?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you're going to be able to write this in a trigger is if you use an INSTEAD OF trigger, one that fires on an action, but does not perform that action at all. If you don't you'll get *ORA-04091: table A is mutating, trigger/function may not see it*, this is because you're trying to modify a table that is currently in the process of being modified in the same session.

You've tried to get around this be performing your updates asynchronously with `DBMS_JOB` [(note that `DBMS_JOB` is deprecated in 10g in favour of `DBMS_SCHEDULER`)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm#BABHCBFD). This won't really work either - you can come up against concurrency issues and you're not solving the essential issue - that people are inserting data into a table that is designed for something else.

The answer to your question is to change the expectations of what the table is there for. You can *only* do this be adding a unique key to the column `BATCH`. From what you've said, this is your natural key. Applications should be expecting that there is only one row when interacting with this table and should be developed with this in mind.

Obviously, this doesn't solve your problem with all the legacy applications. But, there is an answer for that as well.

1. Rename the table to something else (bear with me).
2. Create a view on the table with an identical name to the table.
3. Create an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger on the view, as suggested above - this means that whenever anyone attempts to interact with the table incorrectly you deal with it immediately. This trigger should use a [`MERGE` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm).

Something like:

```
rename test1 to real_test1;
alter table test1 add constraint uk_test1 unique (batch);
create or replace view test1 as select * from real_test1;

create or replace trigger tr_test1
 instead of insert on test1
 for each row
declare

   merge into real_test1 o
   using ( select :new.batch as batch
                , :new.value as value
             from dual ) n
      on (o.batch = n.batch)
    when matched then
         update
            set o.value = o.value + n.value
    when not matched then
         insert (o.batch, o.value)
         values (n.batch, n.value);
end tr_test;
```

This means that:

- if anyone accesses the old table then they see the view, and not see any changes
- if anyone tries the old way of updating the table then they get caught and dealt with properly
- all updates to your table are dealt with immediately and in a consistent manner

More importantly, it tells your users what this table is for and starts training them on proper usage. If you can, log the people who're still trying to insert rows and get them to start merging instead.

P.S. please don't commit in packages...

Answer (score 0):

Your update should use the entire key (batch, id). At the moment, your DBMS job will update multiple rows.

```
update test1
set value = value_sum
where id = v_id;
```

becomes

```
update test1
set value = value_sum
where batch = v_batch
and id = v_id;
```

There might be a more direct way using statement level triggers after insert (not row level triggers). You would have to read a bit to figure out if that would work or not.

You could also just run the trigger after insert but not after update. An update won't add a new row to the table, so rows shouldn't need to be merged.